# Алгоритм: квадрирование квадрата

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется клетчатая квадратная скатерть N x N клеток. Разрезать её на M квадратных салфеток так, чтобы не нарушить целостность клеток.

Пример: Для N = 5; M = 8 имеется решение, один из вариантов которого приведен на следующем рисунке:[image: пример]

Вопрос: как бы вы решали такую задачу, каким должен быть примерный алгоритм?

Comment: Стандартная задача. Называется "Квадрирование квадрата".

Comment: @Akina , разве это одна и та же задача? В вики, кажется, не написано о таких точных условиях. 
"Квадри́рование квадра́та — задача о разбиении квадрата на конечное число меньших квадратов. В более узком смысле — задача о разбиении квадрата на конечное число попарно неравных между собой квадратов"
А похожую на мою я не нашёл в поиске.

Comment: Чего там искать? Твоя задача - это и есть *задача о разбиении квадрата на конечное число меньших квадратов*. С дополнительным ограничением - заранее заданным количеством этих самых меньших квадратов.

Comment: Поиск в глубину графа

Comment: Для начала можно сгенерировать разбиения числа N на M квадратов (если они существуют - в примере это 25=9+4+4+4+1+1+1+1)  а потом пытаться строить из этих квадратов геометрически

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы у меня возникла необходимость решать подобную задачу, я бы написал одну рекурсивную функцию.

Она бы принимала текущую матрицу занятости клеток квадрата. Первым делом она бы сверяла текущее количество мелких квадратов с заданным. Если равно, то в зависимости от наличия незанятых клеток либо выводила очередное решение, либо просто выход. Если же количество меньше, то она бы перебирала все варианты размещения на пустых клетках ещё одного квадрата (сперва 1*1, потом 2*2, и увеличивала его размер до тех пор, пока есть хотя бы один способ поместить на поле ещё один квадрат), и передавала результат на следующий уровень рекурсии.

Ну и всё собственно...

Конечно, оптимальностью тут не пахнет (сложность что-то типа от O(mn^3) до O(mn^3log(n)) ), зато просто и понятно.